# What is the proper way to close a connection when using ExecuteScalar and EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I haven't found the proper way to close the connection or Dispose when I use Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database and the ExecuteScalar method.
I can't use a **using** block cause object doesn't implement IDisposable. And I haven't figured out how to Dispose if I use a Finally block instead. Do I need to do this, or my first using block will Dispose/Close the connection on the ExecuteScalar ?

This is my code:

```
DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(factory, false);
Database db = ... ;

// Initialize command
using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("XXXXXX"))
{
        object r;

        // Execute command
        using (r = (object)db.ExecuteScalar(dbCommand)) //Getting error here
        {
            //Other code here
        }
}
```

Comment: Refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648933.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The second using statement is not required. 
Here the object that should be disposed is `dbCommand`. Not the objects returned from it's methods.
The first `using` statement takes care of it.

If you do not want to use `using` at all, (on the dbCommand) then you can dispose with `try/finally` in finally block.
Below link explains how to do that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects